# How can I get EF6 to work with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-4.7.2

I am using EF6 and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` for Managed Identity.
I have configured the web.config as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SCContext" providerName="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server= 
<myserver>;Authentication=Active Directory Default;Database=TestDB" 
 />

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="SqlClient Data Provider"
          invariant="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
          description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SqlServer"
          type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>


In the code I have defined the following:

 private MyContext _context;  <----MyContext is of type DbContext
 public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

But if I call something like

```
  _context.Users.Find(<guid>);
```

It gives an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.'

TargetFramework is .Net Framework 4.7.2

Any ideas as to how I can fix this ?

Comment: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` - .netstandard;; `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` - .net framework. You need to normalize your references

Comment: sorry what do you mean by that. i have searched the solution there is no reference to System.Data.SqlClient only Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, unless there is something hidden that has been missed

Comment: I had to also install the nuget package ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServer

Comment: First thing, add a tag to your question, what is your target framework?

Comment: it is .Net Framework 4.7.2, not sure where to add the tag , but i edited the original question

Comment: The question is closed ? I have followed the suggested answer , but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: @Sarah What, _exactly_ happened, when you used ErikEJ's library then? Include **all** error details, including the full stack trace and show us how you're instantiating your `DbContext` instances.

Comment: @Sarah Also, you really should update to .NET Framework 4.8.1 by now...

Comment: @Dai why OP needs to use some 3dr party library? You're siting an answer that shouldn't even be a valid answer because this is just link.

Comment: @T.S. As far as I can tell, yes, they need to use a third-party library like that as there is no support in stock EF6 for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` - I understand ErikEJ's library does some internal reflection tricks to make it work with EF6. I do agree with you that ErikEJ's posted answer is inadequate and I've prodded him to expand on it - but I maintain this question is a dupe of that older Q (even if the exact exception message is different).

Comment: I dont get what you mean ? are you saying that i should not use a 3rd party plugin ? I have updated to .NET Framework 4.8.1

Comment: @Sarah Let's take a step back first... _why_ are you doing this? Why are you wanting to shoehorn `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` into EF6?

Comment: @Sarah The real question here is in your question title -*"How can I get EF6 to work with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?"* If you use net472, why do you need to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` if you can naturally use `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: Because i am using Managed Identities to login to a Azure db.

Comment: and looks like following that link actually worked. But I just upgraded to .net 4.8.1 , not sure if that was it . so i think i will start from scratch .. Upgrade to .net 4.8.1 test and if not then to the 3rd party framework

Comment: At this point I am not sure how managed identities are related to entity framework

Comment: Managed identities are only possible with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient , hence the need for it

Comment: But i look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-7.0    So i assume that i can upgrade from EF6 to EF Core and it should work , if im not mistaken ?

Comment: @Sarah EF Core doesn't work on .NET Framework 4.x - you'll need to start-over with a .NET 7 project. **or** you could target .NET Core 3.1 which is the only platform that supports both EF6 and EFCore, but I think that's a waste of time now, imo.

Comment: Ok , yes i just read that .. so the best thing for the moment would be to use the 3rd party nuget package  along with upgrading to .net framework 4.8.1 , you think that would be the best option for now ?